# Scala/Java Redis In Memory

Tags: java, scala, redis, mocking

I'd like to write code that writes to Redis and I hate writing code that doesn't have unit tests, so I'm looking for an in-memory Redis in Scala or Java.

I've searched Dr. Google and came across a few mocks, they are all either unstable or not active (i.e. no commits in the past few months) and I'm looking for something closer to the real thing.

So the question is: an in-memory Redis available for Scala/Java?

Comment: I don't mean to devalue redis, but how hard can it be to write a class that wraps around a hashmap with gets and puts for several types? Mock doesn't need snapshotting or journaling or running cross-platform in a distributed environement, it just needs to return y for some x.

Comment: @slouc you're right. The question is bad. What I actually need is an in-memory Redis that will also test all the little intricacies of the service.

Comment: @slouc - rephrase the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of mocking redis you can use a redis container in your unit test using tools like https://github.com/whisklabs/docker-it-scala